# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems gdrive

Tags: java, android, api

Here's my code.

My program to upload files to gdrive:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

// main function  
public class DriveCommandLine 
{
// providing id and user 
  private static String CLIENT_ID = "686430-a05tdl7fbkrkuf3cd1029ivhst8rocuo.apps.googleusercontent.com";
  private static String CLIENT_SECRET = "nI-SthRC4UU0P__ow";

  private static String REDIRECT_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE)).setAccessType("online").setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();

    String url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).build();
    System.out.println("Please open the following URL in your browser then type the authorization code:");
    System.out.println("  " + url);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String code = br.readLine();

    GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setFromTokenResponse(response);

    //Create a new authorized API client
    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).build();

    //Insert a file  
    File body = new File();
    body.setTitle("My document");
    body.setDescription("A test document");
    body.setMimeType("text/plain");

    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("document.txt");
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", fileContent);

    File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
    System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
  }
}
```

Getting error as:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:     DriveScopes cannot be resolved to a variable    Drive cannot
>   be resolved to a type     Drive cannot be resolved to a type  File cannot
>   be resolved to a type     File cannot be resolved to a type   File cannot
>   be resolved to a type
>
> at gdrive.DriveCommandLine.main(DriveCommandLine.java:33)

Can any one help me?

Comment: include jar files properly for your imports and compile.

Comment: ya have included "google-api-services-drive-v2-[version].jar" ,,, then ly got error..!

Comment: Did my provided idea help you?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you get the error **while executing your app** and you work with Eclipse, this should solve your problem:

1. remove your 3rd-party libraries from the build path
2. create a folder in your Android project called `libs`
3. copy your 3rd-party libraries into the new created folder
4. add the **copied** libraries to the build path

What I remember is, that the libraries must be physically present in an Android project to be exported to the resulting "App file".